# @Bean configuration for inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

```
<spring.framework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
```

I would like to convert xml based integration configuration to a @Configuration class. Specifically how to convert

```
<int:channel id="files"/>
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
                                  channel="files"
                                  directory="file:${local.send.dir}"
                                  filename-pattern="*.txt"
                                  prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="${poll.millis}" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="files"
                       ref="fileActivator"/>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel files() {
    DirectChannel chnl = new DirectChannel();

    return chnl;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "files")
public MessageSource<File> filesIn() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File(env.getProperty("local.send.dir")));
    source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));

    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, but you need `@EnableIntegration` on at least one of your `@Configuration` classes to signal the creation of the SI infrastructure.

If `fileActivator` is a POJO, annotate the method with `@ServiceActivator` and add it as a `@Bean`.

If it's a `MessageHandler` add `@ServiceActivator` to the `@Bean` definition.